# Как изменить кодировку с помощью миграций?

Tags: mysql, yii2

Сейчас при записи рус.слов в БД получаю ???????. Как с помощью миграции изменить кодировку бд под русский текст?

Comment: У тебя база должна быть создана в utf-8

Comment: @SultanovShamil так и есть, но русские буквы не показывает, только после перехода на utf8_general_ci начало работать.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Никак. Верный путь - описать в руководстве, что база должна быть соответствующей кодировки, в переменных окружения и / или в конфиге задать аналогичную кодировку, и уже после начинать создавать структуру базы миграциями.

Тот, кто создавал инструмент миграций, ни по каким соображениям не мог предположить, что на этапе разработки приложения может понадобиться менять кодировку БД. Первая, главная и последняя причина, почему он это не мог сделать - потому что в случае автоматической миграции на новую версию БД, будь там указано, что нужно сменить кодировку, все данные полетят к чертям, а значит и смысл в автоматизации такого действия посредством миграций отсутствует.

Comment: Правильно ли я понял, человеку который будет разворачивать проект, при создании базы, должен сам указать кодировку для БД как указано будет в руководстве?

Comment: @Fitstd абсолютно верно. Обычно это указывается либо в руководстве, либо ставится какая-то кодировка по умолчанию (utf blah blah blah), либо кодировка БД подсматривается в приложении, благо что она всегда там будет указана или же будет написано, какая используется по умолчанию, опять же.

Comment: А, последнее будет верно потому, что практически весь функционал, который вы можете использовать для подключения к базе, в любом языке программирования, потребует у вас так или иначе указанную кодировку БД. Именно поэтому в случае всяческих движков и фреймворков вы всегда найдете в их переменных конфига этот параметр.